# Retrieve data in Firebase exactly once

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a real time database with firebase and i'm using the following code to connect to the database and get some data from it.

```
window.onload = function(){
var databaseWebsites = firebase.database().ref('/websites').orderByChild('votes');
console.log(databaseWebsites);
databaseWebsites.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

      var webTemp = document.getElementById(childSnapshot.val().id);
      webTemp.style.order = order;
      var webText = webTemp.getElementsByClassName('likeText');
      webText[0].innerHTML = childSnapshot.val().votes;
      order--;
  });

  order = 0;
});
```

It gets all the data, in order and uses it correctly.

The problem is, I don't want the data on the front end to update until the user refreshes the page. The system is a voting system that is ordered by votes value, if it was constantly updating it would be a bad user experience.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the `on` to `once`, Firebase `on` listens for changes in your database node and sends a response.

```
databaseWebsites.on('value', function(snapshot) {
```

to

```
databaseWebsites.once('value', function(snapshot) {
```

*An excerpt from Firebase doc*

> The value event is called every time data is changed at the specified
>   database reference, including changes to children. To limit the size
>   of your snapshots, attach only at the lowest level needed for watching
>   changes.

[Visit this url to read more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted response is not correct (maybe outdated?) because `once()` requires to add a `then()`

It's actually

```
databaseWebsites.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {}
```

that replaces

```
databaseWebsites.on('value', function(snapshot) {}
```